# What is the best approach to store a pdf file?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

**Good day all,**

Please forgive me if this isn't the right forum to ask this question - but I couldn't think of a more resourceful community.

I handle IT stuff for a small firm where I built a PCI Compliant VB.net application to store credit card information.  When a customer gives authorization to keep their card information on file, they are required to sign an Authorization Form.  All has been successful thus far, but now they want to be able to store a pdf copy of this authorization form and make it accessible via the application.

I've been thinking of the following ways accomplish this task:

1. FTP (separate from the DB)
2. BLOB (directly in the DB)

What's the best approach to achieve this and how would I go about coding this in VB.net?  I'm using a MySQL database.

//Kismet

Answer (score 2):

Separate from the DB... just save the URL or file path in the database.  In this case then you could split the PDF's up across multiple servers if needed.  Also keeps the size of the DB smaller (which you want to backup more frequently).

Comment: But on the other hand you have to backup two places (database and file space) and keep the backups synchronous. Just to keep in mind :-)